# custom library is not working in code-igniter v3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created a custum library and it is working on localhost ci-v2. But if i am tring to use it in live server having ci v3 it is showing me error .

Please take a look on my controller -:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('smtp_email/smtp_email');
        $mail = new smtp_email();
        echo "here you are "; die();
  }
```

My libraries folder look like -:

```
/application/libraries/smtp_email/
                               smtp_email.php
                               class.phpmailer.php
                               class.smtp.php
```

Error -:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to load the requested class: Smtp_email

Comment: CI 3 needs uppercased names, is file name: "Smtp_email.php"?

Comment: working perfectly  "CI 3 needs uppercased names, is file name: "Smtp_email.php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "CI 3" file name should be start with uppercase letter like Smtp_mail.php try this one.